# How can I sum multiple fields in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I want to get the sum of multiple fields.  I use this code to explain my pain:

```
 // parse the data, group it, window it, and aggregate the counts
 val windowCounts = text
      .flatMap { w => w.split("\\s") }
      .map { w => WordWithCount(w, 1, 2) }
      .keyBy("word")
      .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(1))
      .sum("count")

case class WordWithCount(word: String, count: Long, count2: Long)
```

I want the sum of both fields (count and count2) in my time windows.
I can't add multiple sums like that:

```
 val windowCounts = text
        .flatMap { w => w.split("\\s") }
        .map { w => WordWithCount(w, 1, 2) }
        .keyBy("word")
        .timeWindow(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(1))
        .sum("count", "count2")
```

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: And what do you think about using the map function to create a stream of tuples with any key and the sum of two fields values at the beginning and use the aggregation after that?

Comment: With the solution of @FabianHueske it work fine, I use reduceFunction with custom Sum. 
``` 
stream
.map(x => transfom(x))
.keyBy("field")
.timeWindow(Time.milliseconds(10000), Time.milliseconds(1000))
.reduce((x, y) => Custom.sum(x, y))
```

Answer (score 2):

The DataSteam API does not offer built-in operators to sum multiple fields.

There are two options:

1. Implement a custom [`ReduceFunction`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/windows.html#reducefunction) that sums both fields.
2. Have a look at Flink's [Table API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table/tableApi.html) or [SQL support](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table/sql.html). Both can perform multiple aggregations on a group window.